# How can i check if two points are connected on the pictureBox then enable true button4?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in Form1 of the pictureBox1 mouse down event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
                label4.Visible = true;
                if (wireObject1 == null)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    float t = wireObject1.GetIndexByXY(e.X, e.Y, 5);

                    if (t == -1)
                    {
                        button3.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (pointDeletion == false)
                        {
                            button3.Enabled = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button3.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        {
                            selectedIndex = t;
                            mouseMove = true;
                            OriginalX = wireObject1._point_X[(int)selectedIndex];
                            OriginalY = wireObject1._point_Y[(int)selectedIndex];



                            if (cyclicSelectedIndex.Count() == 2)
                            {

                                cyclicSelectedIndex[currentCyclicIndex] = (int)selectedIndex;
                                currentCyclicIndex++;
                                if (currentCyclicIndex == 2)
                                {
                                    currentCyclicIndex = 0;
                                }
                                if ((cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) || (cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == -1) || (cyclicSelectedIndex[1] == -1))
                                {
                                    button2.Enabled = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    button2.Enabled = true;
                                }

                                for (int i = 0; i < wireObject1._connectionstart.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    if ((wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                       (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]) ||
                                        wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0] || wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] ||
                                         wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] || wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0])
                                    {
                                        button3.Enabled = false;
                                    }

                                    if ((wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                       (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]))
                                    {
                                        button2.Enabled = false;
                                    }

                                    if ((wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                        (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                        (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]) ||
                                        (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]))
                                    {
                                        button4.Enabled = true;

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        button4.Enabled = false;
                                    }  
                                }
                                label13.Text = selectedIndex.ToString();
                                label13.Visible = true;
                                label14.Visible = true;
                                listView1.Items.Add(selectedIndex.ToString()).EnsureVisible();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have a button click event, and when i click it's adding(drawing) a point on the `pictureBox1`.
So i add/click 6 times and add 6 points.
Now i can drag them around the `pictureBox1` area.
Then i click on another button to draw a line between two selected points.
When i make the click on a point in the `pictureBox` mouse down event i select a point then select second point and click to connect them with a line.

In the end i have 6 points with 3 lines each two points are connected between them with a drawn line.

Now what i want to do in the `pictureBox` mouse down event is that when ever i select two points which are connected with a line between them turn `button4.enabled = true`.
If i clicked on any point which is not connect turn `button4.enabled = false`.

So i tried to do it like this:

```
if ((wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                        (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                        (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]) ||
                                        (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]))
                                    {
                                        button4.Enabled = true;

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        button4.Enabled = false;
                                    }
```

But its not working in all cases .

Now:

`wireObject1._connectionstart` is a `List<int>` and also `wireObject1._connectionend` is a `List<int>` they are containing the starting and ending of each connected/line between two points.

`cyclicSelectedIndex` is `List<int>`. [0] contain the first clicked/selected point and [1] the second selected/clicked point.

What i did when i click on a point so its doing : wireObject1.GetIndexByXY
which find the nearest center of the point i clicked so i know i selected this point i wanted and not one near it .

---

In the end what i need is to check when click/select two points if they are connected with a line(connection) between them `button4.enabled = true` ELSE `button4.enabled = false`.

( I know the code and descriptions are long tried to make it shortest as i can sorry )

Comment: Please separate UI code from logic to simplify your code and isolate your problem. Also "But its not working in all cases ." is very bad description of your problem, so please after separating code add tests the show the issue so one can easier time helping you.

Comment: why are you using lists instead of arrays of two or 2 members? what's the point of using lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to debug and see what's going wrong. it should pop to your eye if you do it step by step. as it seems, you are doing `wireObject1.GetIndexByXY(e.X, e.Y, 5);` witch probably don't return the right value, or your if statement doing some wired stuff, like checking if a dot is connected to itself:

```
wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) && (wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]
```

how can an single index be the start and end of a point.
to make long story short, run the method line by line, see that the index are inserted to the data structure properly, and check the variables on the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the right IF allready .
Just added the button4.Enabled true or false and break;

```
if ((wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                       (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]))
                                    {
                                        button2.Enabled = false;
                                        button4.Enabled = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        button4.Enabled = false;
                                    }
```

From the tests i did so far everything seems to be working fine.
I hope im right.

Thanks.